# Parameter value [2018-04-08T11:02:44] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to send this XML to rest api server:

XML Request:

```
<reconcile>
  <start_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</start_date>
  <end_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</end_date>
  <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

JAXB code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "reconcile")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Reconcile {

    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    public String page;
```

SQL query:

```
public List<PaymentTransactions> transactionsByDate(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date) throws Exception {

        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date));
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
        return paymentTransactions;
    }
```

But when I make request I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-04-08T11:02:44] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

Do I need to convert the Date value before I send it as param for the SQL query?
Or I need use other type of Date?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are setting `start_date`, which is a `LocalDateTime`, as the parameter for the SQL; the error message tells you it wants a `java.util.Date`, and that it does not understand a `LocalDateTime` object. You'll need to convert it:

```
Date startDate = Date.from(start_date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
Date endDate = Date.from(end_date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql)
                  .setParameter(0, startDate).setParameter(1, endDate));
```

(This is assuming that you're using `java.time.LocalDateTime` and that you want to use the default time zone of your system).

This is necessary because JPA / Hibernate does unfortunately not (yet) automatically understand the relatively new `java.time` classes (it requires you to use the old `java.util.Date` class).

Comment: Hibernate has support for the `java.time` classes since 5.0 in a separate module, and since 5.2 it's built-in.

Comment: @coladict I've included Hibernate version 5.5.6-final in my Maven pom, and I still have error because I'm using DateTime as an argument for query

Comment: @Jesper but if I use your solution, data about time is lost?

Comment: @LosmiNCL No. A `java.util.Date` is actually a timestamp (date + time) despite its name. (The bad name is just one of the [many problems with `java.util.Date`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)).

Comment: @LosmiNCL you can use Jesper's solution, but you have to use `setParameter(index, startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`, and the parameter indexes start at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 8):

Because you use `createQuery` and JPQL, the expected type is determined during parsing, and the one you've specified in the `PaymentTransactions` class is `java.util.Date`.

Just change the type of `created_at` inside the `PaymentTransactions` class to `LocalDateTime`. It's fully supported by Hibernate's recent versions.